# .NET ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Tags: sql, .net, oracle, dbcommand

I am trying to construct named parameters but receive an error.

> Couldn't get data from Database
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException ORA-01858: a non-numeric
>   character was found where a numeric was expected    at
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper...

```
private static void AddCriteria(IDbCommand command, string column, object value, string sqlOperator = "=")
{
    var parameter = command.CreateParameter();

    if (value is DateTime)
    {
        value = FormatSqlDate((DateTime)value);
    }

    parameter.ParameterName = DbHelper.GetParameterSql(parameter, "P" + (command.Parameters.Count + 1));
    parameter.Value = value;
    command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

    command.CommandText += string.Format(" {0} {1} {2} {3}", (command.Parameters.Count > 1 ? "AND" : "WHERE"), column, sqlOperator, parameter.ParameterName);
}
```

Following query is constructed:

```
SELECT *
FROM trade LEFT JOIN 
     findetail
     ON trade.trade = findetail.trade LEFT JOIN
     fintransact 
     ON findetail.fintransact = fintransact.fintransact
WHERE trade.trade = :P1 AND acctdate = :P2
```

While parameters are

```
:P1 - 2298056
:P2 - TO_DATE('2014-12-31T00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: P2 should not contain the TO_DATE function and its parameter but only the DateTime value. The remainder should go in the query text

Answer (score 0):

Variables can only be values. You cannot have a function call like `TO_DATE` as text in a variable.

You need to put all SQL in the query text and only extract the real variables (like the actual time) into bound variables.

In this case, why don't you pass a properly parsed .NET `DateTime` as your value?